# Трансформация DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, статистика

Есть 2 `pd.DataFrame`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[1, 20], [2, 25], [3, 24], [1, 22], [2, 29]], columns=['type', 'size'])
b = pd.DataFrame([[1, 19], [1, 21], [2, 24], [4, 21]], columns=['type', 'size'])
```

В каждый DataFrame хочу добавить столбцы следующего типа

```
a['amount_mean_type'] = a['size'] / a.groupby('type')['size'].transform('mean')
a['amount_std_type'] = a['size'] / a.groupby('type')['size'].transform('std')
```

Вопрос в том, как мне сделать так, чтобы в `b['amount_mean_type']` и `b['amount_std_type']` я использовал `mean` и `std` по группам из `a`, а по тем категориям, которых нет в `a`, использовать `mean` и `std` по всему сету (если это корректно).

Что-то вроде этого:

```
b['amount_mean_type'] = b['size'] / a.groupby('type')['size'].transform('mean')
b['amount_std_type'] = b['size'] / a.groupby('type')['size'].transform('std')
```

Но только с теми условиями, которые описал выше

**UPD: пример фреймов на выходе**

Для `a` все просто:

```
a['amount_mean_type'] = a['size'] / a.groupby('type')['size'].transform('mean')
a['amount_std_type'] = a['size'] / a.groupby('type')['size'].transform('std')

  type size amount_mean_type amount_std_type
0   1   20  0.952381    14.142136
1   2   25  0.925926    8.838835
2   3   24  1.000000    NaN 
3   1   22  1.047619    15.556349
4   2   29  1.074074    10.253048
```

для `b` приходится прописать вручную каждую операцию

```
b.loc[0, 'amount_mean_type'] = b.loc[0, 'size'] / a[a['type'] == 1]['size'].mean()
b.loc[1, 'amount_mean_type'] = b.loc[1, 'size'] / a[a['type'] == 1]['size'].mean()
b.loc[2, 'amount_mean_type'] = b.loc[2, 'size'] / a[a['type'] == 2]['size'].mean()
b.loc[3, 'amount_mean_type'] = b.loc[3, 'size'] / a['size'].mean()

b.loc[0, 'amount_std_type'] = b.loc[0, 'size'] / a[a['type'] == 1]['size'].std()
b.loc[1, 'amount_std_type'] = b.loc[1, 'size'] / a[a['type'] == 1]['size'].std()
b.loc[2, 'amount_std_type'] = b.loc[2, 'size'] / a[a['type'] == 2]['size'].std()
b.loc[3, 'amount_std_type'] = b.loc[3, 'size'] / a['size'].std()

  type size amount_mean_type amount_std_type
0   1   19  0.904762    13.435029
1   1   21  1.000000    14.849242
2   2   24  0.888889    8.485281
3   4   21  0.875000    6.192562 # Считается по всей переменной 'type', так как категории (4) нет в `a`
```

Фреймы `a` и `b` можно рассматривать как `train` и `test` соответственно

Comment: Добавил. Это пример, на деле у меня будет несколько столбцов типа Type [astype('object')] и 1 столбец типа Size [astype('number')] - по нему я хочу считать статистики

Comment: @MaxU, скажите, пожалуйста, я правильно понял комментарий про таблицу/фрейм, который я хочу получить на выходе?

Comment: Да, сейчас все стало понятно. Попробую ответить завтра, когда доберусь до компа...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tmp = a.groupby('type')['size'].agg(["mean", "std"])

res = (b.assign(x=b["type"].map(tmp["mean"]).fillna(a["size"].mean()))
        .eval("amount_mean_type = size / x")
        .drop(columns="x"))

res = (res.assign(x=b["type"].map(tmp["std"]).fillna(a["size"].std()))
          .eval("amount_std_type = size / x")
          .drop(columns="x"))
```

результат:

```
In [28]: res
Out[28]:
   type  size  amount_mean_type  amount_std_type
0     1    19          0.904762        13.435029
1     1    21          1.000000        14.849242
2     2    24          0.888889         8.485281
3     4    21          0.875000         6.192562
```

Comment: спасибо!  Действительно, очень удобно получается делать расчет при помощи переменной tmp с дальнейшим методом map(), а также открыл для себя новый метод - eval()

Comment: @ИльяМитусов, был рад помочь)